# Autocomplete lookup

Tags: metadata

I have a question regarding metadata. Let's say I am the administrator of a soccer team, where new players come in (and "old" players go out) every other week. If I have documents in my library containing "Players" (as, for instance, metadata-tags) how could I:

1) Choose e.g. 3 names (of players) at ones from a list/metadata-field? (something like holding down ctrl and hit one player's name, and then another's and so forth from a drilldown list).

2) administrate the metadata field in a reasonable way? If new players come in and old ones go out every other week, then it'll be a hell of a job adding and subtracting names to the list all the time.

Hope someone understands my question and takes the time to answer it. It would've helped me so much!

Best,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean that you have a list called Players which contains items which represent the players. It may not make sense to use managed metadata.

Instead, maybe you should have all of the team members in the list. Add a column called "Playing" or something and make it a Yes/No column. Then each week simply check the boxes for those who are playing. You can set ip a view to only display the items where the value is Yes.

Comment: Thanks. But, let's say, I have 1.000 players (or 10.000) in a list (i.e. in a dropdown box). Now, I will create a document where I am supposed to put together a team of 11 players. How can I pick out 11 players all at once from such a dropdown window? Is it possible for me to type in just some of the characters in a players name, in order to automatically hit that player directly (amongst 1.000 other names). It would have saved me a lot of work, if I wouldn't have to search through 1.000 names to find the player I was looking for. If so, how can I perform such a "free-text-search"?

Comment: Managed Metadata would give you the type ahead you desire, although there are [limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262787(Office.14).aspx#termstore) to the number of terms you can have in a set. 

You might also want to explore a custom field type along the lines of [SharePoint 2010 Autocomplete Lookup Field](http://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks alot, @ciphertxt. Are you familiar with autocomplete lookup? I think that is exactly what I've been looking for. What he does in the example, is that he first types in a list of companies (types in each company of the portfolio of companies). When he has added the companies he wants to choose from, he can just type 'Xe' and Xerox will automatically appear. Then he types e.g. 'Me' and Mercer appears automatically. Finally he types 'App' and Applied Information Sciences pops up. Am I right? Do you have som more details to clarify things? It is much appreciated!

Comment: I think it depends greatly on what you want to do with the "team" once you've entered all of the players. For instance, a multi-select People Picker would let you pick all of the players and they would be stored in one item's column.

Comment: Thank you for response @Marc. I can ask you, as well: Are you familiar with autocomplete lookup? If you have been watching the example ciphertxt refered to, I have a question regarding that last screenshot (the picture at the bottom of the page).
1) Where do I write the codes listed to get a autocomplete lookup (in order to just type a few letters of a word and get an automatic suggestion of the complete word)?
2) Is it a simple task to add multiple items (e.g. companies as in the example) in one dialog box?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with that Codeplex project. I'd always use jQueryUI and SPServices to do something like that. You had originally asked about managed metadata. It gives you what amounts to an autocomplete function with the Taxonomy Picker. Have you used it yet?

Comment: Ok. I have not used it yet. I am trying to figure out how I am going to set up the final solution. I suppose I still have a lot of work to do before I am near that solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I find the best approach to SharePoint development (especially the type you seem to be doing) is to just jump in and see how it works. You'll answer many of your own questions.